# RTL issue in IE affecting whole page

Tags: css, internet-explorer, right-to-left

I'm developing a website in hebrew, and everything is fine in Chrome and Firefox (as expected), but I have an issue with IE.
When I place

```
direction:RTL;
unicode-bidi:embed;
```

the whole page gets shifted to the right, and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

On initial load of the page, IE loads it scrolled to the right side, so it looks good (no need for manual scrolling), but the horizontal scrollbar is there.

All the other elements are placed correctly and I can't find the issue. There is no element that would overflow outside the main wrapper, and the scrollbar is there only if `direction:RTL` is placed.

I can notice that the scrollbar appears near the end of the loading, but I don't know if there is some way to step through the loading of the page (something like breakpoint/debug/step).

I tested it on 3 different computers (IE8/XP, IE8/Win7, IE9/Win7, and also with http://netrenderer.com )

Some help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

You can check it at:

http://southbeachsmoke.co.il/

http://southbeachsmoke.co.il/products/category/1

Comment: If you look at the page on IE 9 and use developer tools (press F12), you can see that the `body` element width is very large and gets even larger on zooming (Ctrl +). The page uses several large libraries, and the odds are that some of them uses tricks that don’t work well with RTL, e.g. position elements far to the left to get them out of the viewport.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela

When testing, I've placed border on every element using `*{border:1px solid #00ff00;}` and I don't see elements outside the body.


Also when inspecting the element with the developer tools on IE8, the body width is same as the viewport (when selected it gets a blue border), but the page (<html>) is about 1000px wider (hence the scrollbar).

Comment: The problem does not appear on IE 9 if I disable client-side scripting.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thank you very much for the guidance, after disabling the scripts one by one, I finally found that the ShareThis widget is the one causing the issue. I have to go with the Bagavatu suggestion for now, because trying to fix this widget causes some other unwanted results which might require a new SO question.